# Brew installed, linked, but not found

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, homebrew

I just installed `mtr` via Homebrew, and it completed seemingly successfully (i.e., nothing unusual).

```
MBA% mtr
zsh: command not found: mtr
```

That's odd. I figured I'd try again:

```
MBA% brew install mtr
Warning: mtr-0.86 already installed
```

Okay, maybe it's symlinked as `mtr-0.86`:

```
MBA% mtr-0.86
zsh: command not found: mtr-0.86
```

Nope, okay, maybe it just failed to link:

```
MBA% brew link mtr
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.86
To relink: brew unlink mtr && brew link mtr
MBA% brew unlink mtr && brew link mtr
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.86... 3 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.86... 2 symlinks created
MBA% mtr zsh: command not found: mtr
```

However:

```
MBA% /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.86/sbin/mtr
[Success]
```

What's going on? Why is Homebrew failing to link (and creating fewer symlinks on relinking for that matter..)?

Comment: (Keen-eyed may note that `mtr` needs root. Yes. By *[Success]* I mean it complained about just that, rather than failing to even run.)

Answer (score 20):

I saw the same when installing brew 0.86. While most binaries get linked to /usr/local/bin, brew get's linked to /usr/local/sbin. This is absolutely right but you need to extend your path in order to avoid typing the whole path.

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`

will fix it once and you will need to adjust your .bash_profile to fix it permanently

Comment: Since macOS no longer uses bash as the default shell, it would be better to edit `/etc/paths` instead of `.bash_profile`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288733/266535

Answer (score 15):

For mtr v0.86 and below:

```
brew install mtr
ln /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.86/sbin/mtr /usr/local/bin/mtr
sudo mtr superuser.com
```

But since mtr v0.87 one more command is needed:

```
ln /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.92/sbin/mtr-packet /usr/local/bin/mtr-packet
```

Comment: Actually mtr was already in /usr/local/sbin. The solution of adding /usr/local/sbin to the PATH is better.

Answer (score 2):

Add `/usr/local/sbin` to current `PATH` variable and make persistent.

```bash
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
echo '/usr/local/sbin' | sudo tee -a /etc/paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72387809/602072

> NOTE: For Apple Silicon machines the PATH is different.
>
> Add this line(s) to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`
>
> ```
> # Intel export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
>
> # Apple Silicon export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/sbin
> ```
>
> Run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` or close/open your
> terminal.
>
> Then run mtr as usual
>
> ```
> sudo mtr 1.1.1.1
> ```